# Django Johnny cache - include tables instead of exclude using MAN_IN_BLACKLIST?

Tags: django, django-cache, django-johnny-cache

I'm aware of Johnny cache's `MAN_IN_BLACKLIST` and `JOHNNY_TABLE_BLACKLIST`.
Is there a way to specify the reverse? That is specify only the tables that need to be cached?
I want to do this for the simple reason that we have over 200 tables in the application and I want to cache a few and don't want my `MAN_IN_BLACKLIST` to be really huge.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing tables explicitly, I'm afraid you need to hack `johnny/cache.py`, mainly lines contains `blacklist_match`. The easiest way is to modify the function `blacklist_match` directly:

```
# set WHITELIST in johnny/settings.py, just as BLACKLIST
WHITELIST = getattr(settings, 'MAN_IN_WHITELIST',
            getattr(settings, 'JOHNNY_TABLE_WHITELIST', []))
WHITELIST = set(WHITELIST)

def blacklist_match(*tables):
    return not WHITELIST.issuperset(tables) or \
           bool(settings.BLACKLIST.intersection(tables))
```

Comment: OK, Thanks. I also see that if I fire a raw select query using the django db connection/cursor it doesn't seem to cache the result. Is that by design? Or is it possible to cache those results as well?

Comment: @ksrini Yes, Johnny monkey-patches sqlcompiler for normal Query, and do not wrap `QuerySet.raw()` and `db.cursor()`.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.4 Johnny Cache actually supports whitelists.
Add `JOHNNY_TABLE_WHITELIST` to your settings and assign it the list of tables you want to be cached, e.g.:

```
JOHNNY_TABLE_WHITELIST = ['appname_tablename', 'someotherapp_differenttable']
```

[source](http://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/queryset_cache.html#settings)